# Github pages description column

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, readme

I am working with github pages using jekyll.
I created table in .md file and one of the columns is description one. It is fulfilled with long description and my vscode auto formats and breaks table's style.

I would like it to be as long as I want. It should work with scroll, without text breaks to new lines.

How can I achieve it?